# Picasso load large photos with resize option doesn't work well

Tags: android, picasso

I'm using picasso to load all the local images as below:

```
Picasso.with(mContext).load("path").resize(270,270).centerCrop().into(iv)
```

But in some cellphone, big images(such as the photos taken by camera) won't show if i use the `resize(270, 270)`.But some works well.

I don't know how to compatble with all the cellphones.

Comment: if you use the resize with different value or don't use resize. does it work well

Comment: If i don't use resize, it's ok.The official has replyed to me, it's a bug and been fixed in new version of picasso

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about which phones are compatible with picasso but you can try `Universal Image Loader` or `Glide` and check if they work well